# How to use bindingsource with image from grid to picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I use bindingsource to binding picture form datagridview to picture:

```
picProductImage.DataBindings.Add("Image", bsBase, dsProduct.Product.ImageColumn.ColumnName,true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation,"","binary")
```

but i receive exeption:

```
    the following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. At System.drawing.Image.Fromstream(Stream stream, Boolean use EmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
at System.Drawing.ImageConverter.convertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.FormatObjectInternal(Object value, Type targetType, TypeConvert sourceConverter, TypeConverter targetConverter,String formatString, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue)
at System.Windoes.Forms.Formatter.FormatObject(Object value, Type targetType, TypeConverter sourceConverter, TypeConverter targetConverter, String formatString, IFormatProvider fomatInfo, Object formattedNullValue, Object dataSourceNullvalue)
at
System.Windows.Form.DatagridViewCell.GetFormattedValue(Object value, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewCellStyle& cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverted, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.
```

I don't know how to binding to picture. any idea? Thanks alot

Comment: "System.Windoes.Forms" are you sure there are typos in the .NET base class libraries?

Comment: i'm not sure, but i dont know how to binding